# AttributeError: ObjectT instance has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python

```
    >>> dir(classAInstance.objectTInstance.__dict__)
    ['__class__', '__cmp__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__delitem__', '__doc__', '__eq__',
 '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__iter__', '__le__',
 '__len__', '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', 
'__setitem__', '__str__', 'clear', 'copy', 'fromkeys', 'get', 'has_key', 'items', 'iteritems', 
'iterkeys', 'itervalues', 'keys', 'pop', 'popitem', 'setdefault', 'update', 'values']

>>> classAInstance.objectTInstance.attB             # Access Method 1
199

>>> classAInstance.objectTInstance.__dict__['attB'] # Access Method 2
199

>>> classAInstance.objectTInstance['attB']          # Access Method 3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in ?
AttributeError: ObjectT instance has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Claim: `classAInstance` is an insance of `ClassA` and `objectTInstance` is an instance of `ObjectT`.

**Question**>where does `classAInstance.objectTInstance` store the attribute `attB`?
And why the Access Method 3 doesn't work? what exactly does `__dict__` store?

```
 object.__dict__
     A dictionary or other mapping object used to store an object’s (writable) attributes.
```

Based on my understanding, Access method 1 and 2 are exactly same. Also the `attB` is stored in the `__dict__` of the object of `ObjectT`. In order to make Access 3 work, ObjectT has to provide a dictionary magic function called `__getitem__`.

Is this correct?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When accessing an attribute via the first method you tried, Python first checks `__dict__` to see if the attribute is in there. If it is, that's what it uses. It then checks the `__dict__` of the `__class__` of the object. If it's still not found, it continues searching superclasses. (If multiple inheritance is involved, it gets more complex.) If it is still not found, it looks for `__getattr__` of the class or any superclasses and calls that to get the attribute. If all of those fail, it errors.

The second method directly accesses the `__dict__` of the object. It will not check the classes' attributes or call `__getattr__` like the first does.

The third method is something else completely; it tries to call `__getitem__` (don't confuse that with `__getattr__`).

Answer (score 1):

The source of your confusion is that you have a dictionary object that has a `__dict__` attribute that also points to a dictionary. *Your object and its `__dict__` attribute are not the same dictionary.*

Most Python objects have a `__dict__` attribute that is used to store attributes of the object; these attributes are accessed using the `.` syntax (which searches the `__dict__` of your object, along with its class and the classes it is derived from). When your object *is* a dictionary, it also stores items *in itself.* These are accessed using the `[...]` syntax.

It is possible to write `__getattr__()` and `__setattr__()` methods on your `dict` subclass that allow items in the dictionary to also be accessed using dot notation, a la JavaScript. This is generally a bad idea because Python programmers don't expect Python to act like JavaScript.